# LINUX bash file: RENAME subdirs by count of files in them

Tags: linux, bash

**1. I want to write LINUX bash file and I want to rename subdirs/FOLDERS by
    count of files in them(and in subfolder if they is present) Example: I have such structure(I had ~300 FOLDERS and with random count of subfolders im them with files)

```
MUSIC
-CD1
 --ELTON
 --MADONA
-CD34
 --SUMER
-CDBESTOF2013
  --WINTER
  --2009
  --2010
-CDGREATTESTHITS 
  --HITS1
  --HITS30
```

**...
...**

```
CD1 had 35 *.mp3 files in ALL SUBFOLDERS
CD34 had 10 *.mp3 files in ALL SUBFOLDERS
CDBESTOF2013 had 300 *.mp3 files in ALL SUBFOLDERS
CDGREATTESTHITS had 99 *.mp3 files in ALL SUBFOLDERS

I want to run Linux bash file to rename/add sufix to subdirs by
count of files in them RESULT:

MUSIC
-CD1_35
-CD34_10
-CDBESTOF2013_300
-CDGREATTESTHITS_99
```

**...
...** 
Thank YOU ...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
for dirs in music/*; do
    count=$(find "$dirs" -type f | wc -l)
    mv "$dirs" "${dirs}_${count}"
done
```

The `for loop` will list all the sub-directories in `music/` and assign each directory name to `$dirs`.

The `count` will get the number of files within the sub-directory.

Comment: @Jay - I would approve your edit but the maxdepth 1 will limit the find to 1 depth. The OP is asking for all files under all sub-folders in each CDs. Can you let me know what your interpretation of the original post?

Answer (score 0):

stuff like this is much easier in perl

```
perl -l -e 'for $i (@ARGV) { $a=()=(<$i/*>); rename  $i, "${i}_${a}"}' dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir4 dirpattern*
```

Comment: THAN YOU VERY MUCH, BUT I NEED --LINUX BASH !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
MYDIR=$PWD
input_dirlist=`ls -l $MYDIR | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'`
for f in $input_dirlist
do

    count=`ls -lR $f| grep ^- | wc -l`
    mv $f $f"_"$count 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this I don't have time to test it

```
   for dir1 in $( find ./ -type d );do
       cnt=$(ls $dir1 | wc -l)
       dir2=$(dirname $dir1)
       mv $dir1 $dir2_${cnt}
    done
```